# Browserify multiple standalone modules that shares or requiring same file

Tags: browserify

I am trying to browserify a set of models/classes which are in separate files and use them as a library with the standalone flag.

I have noticed that some of these models requires the same base class(es) and gets duplicated with browersify on output.

Example:

Foo.js

```
var Base = require('base.js')

class Foo extends Base ...
```

Bar.js

```
var Base = require('base.js')

class Foo extends Base ...
```

Browserify each file..

```
browserify foo.js --standalone Foo > dist/foo.js
browserify bar.js --standalone Bar > dist/bar.js
```

Inside foo.js and bar.js has the base class defined. It works without issues, but I'm curious to know if there is an efficient way to browserify multiple standalone files that some of them requires the same file.

Is it possible to browserify multiple standalone files but share the same base class?